How to embed a productFruit's checklist into a react application
I'm trying to embed a checklist into my react application. It should be visible after a certain button click.
Reading productFruit's documentation I could see that I would need to use the:
window.productFruits.api.checklists.injectToElement(checklistId, yourElement);
I tried applying it to an useEffect hook like this:
 useEffect(() => {
    if (window?.productFruits?.api.checklists) {
      const yourElement = document.getElementById(
        'SideBar-ListItemIconWrapper-Group',
      );
      if (yourElement) {
        try {
          window.productFruits.api.checklists.injectToElement(
            id,
            yourElement,
          );
          console.log('SUCCESS');
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error occurred during injection:', error);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [])

But I keep getting these errors:
'Error occurred during injection: Error: Checklist not found. Possible reasons: 1) wrong ID, 2) checklist was dismissed, 3) checklist is not published'
The id is correct and its published.
I also tried creating a asyncronous functions like this:
  const productFruitsFunction = async () => {
    const yourElement = document.getElementById(
      'SideBar-ListItemIconWrapper-Group',
    );
    const checklistId = id;
    if (
      window.productFruits &&
      window.productFruits.api &&
      window.productFruits.api.checklists
    ) {
      try {
        console.log('test');
        await window.productFruits.api.checklists.injectToElement(
          checklistId,
          yourElement,
        );
        console.log('SUCESSO');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('ERROR: ', error);
      }
    }
  };

But also kept getting the same error.

ProductFruits provides React and NextJS integration and it's best to use their React package.

Install the React NPM package
npm install react-product-fruits --save
Import the package import { ProductFruits } from 'react-product-fruits';
The component must be inserted into the top-most place in your application tree that is possible. If you use React Router, do not use it inside of every route. Put it to the  component directly (not to <Route />) or completely outside of it. If you use NextJS, the safest way is to use the dontDestoy prop.
The component requires a few props. You have to provide the ID of your workspace, current language code, and current user information. For React, <ProductFruits workspaceCode="YOUR_WORKSPACE_CODE" language="LOWER-CASE ISO-2 CODE OF LOCALIZATION LANGUAGE" user={userInfo} />. For NextJS applications, check if the window global variable exists {global.window && <ProductFruits workspaceCode="YOUR_WORKSPACE_CODE" language="LOWER-CASE ISO-2 CODE OF LOCALIZATION LANGUAGE" user={userInfo} />.

Full example:
import React from 'react';
import { ProductFruits } from 'react-product-fruits';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { appUser } = this.props; // you have to provide user information from your store
    
    const userInfo = {
      username: appUser.username,
      email: appUser.email,
      firstname: appUser.firstname,
      lastname: appUser.lastname,
      signUpAt: appUser.signUpAt,
      role: appUser.role,
      props: { customProperty1: 123 }
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <ProductFruits workspaceCode="YOUR_WORKSPACE_CODE" language="LOWER-CASE ISO-2 CODE OF LOCALIZATION LANGUAGE" user={userInfo} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

You can find more in the official guide on Installation to React or NextJS applications.
